# Is there an api for world terrain/biome data?

Tags: data, api, terrain

I'm looking for an api where I pass a lat/lng, and get "Desert" or "Mountains" or "Ocean" back. Just the general biome of the area.

Most of what I've seen involves getting tiles back, so you can display a map, but that's not very useful for my use-case. I'm trying to build a mobile app that changes ui based off where you currently are.

Comment: Reverse Geocoder http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3DRocky%20Mountains can be accessed via the API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse using natural_feature and establishment types

Comment: Desert Example http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3DSaharia%20Desert

Comment: Mapperz, the examples you gave were for passing in a known place (Rocky Mountains, Saharia Desert). I only have the user's lat/lng. As far as I can tell, Google Geocoder will only give a street address, or a city, and won't give something as vague as "Beach".

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I never found anything. My best idea was scraping a mapping API, and doing a color match on the tiles, which wasn't worth the effort.